# Laravel Livewire: How to transfer Data from one route to other in livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, frontend

I have to routes two to views home and cart (regular blade views not livewire)

1. ...app/vendorId/home
   2)...app/vendorId/cart
2. '/home' route has a blade view with a two livewire components the code is shown below
   a) vehicle
   b) products

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @livewire('vehicle-list')
    @livewire('products', ['vendorId'=>$vendorId])
@endsection
```

2. '/cart' will have one livewire component

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @livewire('cart', ['vendorId'=>$vendorId])
@endsection
```

Now I want to get the data selected by the user from home page to the cart page.  How can I do that?  I have tried events but it did not work.

I am stuck at this for a while an help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to dispatch your event using laravel echo instead, because regular livewire emit events work only in the current request.